# What is the markup format for documentation on the parameters of a block in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, documentation, markdown, markup

The parameters of a block in Swift shows up with a table for parameters of the block if you add markup for documentation but I can not figure out how to fill out this table. I have searched for it in the [Xcode markup reference formatting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_markup_formatting_ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016497) but I couldn't find anything on it.

Example:

```
/**
 Foo

 - parameter completion: A block to execute
 */
func foo(completion: (Bool) -> Void) {
    // do something
}
```

This is what shows up if I `option + click` in Xcode on the function above to view documentation:

[image: Image of Xcode documentation view of a function]

Apple's APIs show the completion block parameter table filled out. This is an example of a CloudKit API documentation view:

[image: Image of Xcode documentation view of a function]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to give a name to the parameter, but precede it with an underscore:

```
/**
 Foo

 - parameter completion: A block to execute
 - parameter aflag: Some Bool flag
 */
func foo(completion: (_ aflag: Bool) -> Void) {
    // do something
}
```

[image]

Comment: is it the same for @escaping blocks ? like func captureStill(completion: @escaping(_ capturedImg: UIImage?, _ imageUrl: URL?)->())

Comment: Swift 5 & Xcode 10: I've just come across this with an `@escaping` block: I gave it a "_ name" and a description and it displays the whole thing in the extra boxes. Why is it doing that and how do you make it behave like a normal parameter?

Comment: @Neph It's not working for me now, regardless of `@escaping` or not. Xcode 11.2 / Swift 5.1.

Comment: @MikeTaverne What is it doing instead? I recently updated to Xcode 11 too but sorry, it'll most likely be at least a couple of days before I can check if something changed for my documentation too.

Comment: @MikeTaverne I just checked my iOS 12.2 project in Xcode 11.2: It still looks like in the screenshot you posted (there's an extra table).

Comment: @Neph Xcode 11.3.1 does not display documentation for `result`:
`func login(completion: (_ result: Result<String, Error>) -> Void)`