# Swift documentary: Parameter displayed in extra box

Tags: swift, xcode, code-documentation

Swift 5, Xcode 10.

Writing documentation for my code I came across a problem with `@escaping` that resulted in an extra box with "- No Description" in the documentation window (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38669725/2016165)).

So I changed this:

```
private func myFunc(something: @escaping (FileObject?) -> ()) {}
```

to this (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38669796/2016165) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41971881/2016165)):

```
/**
 Description of myFunc.

 - Parameters:
    - something: Is something.
    - f: Something else.
 */
private func myFunc(something: @escaping (_ f: FileObject?) -> ()) {}
```

which looks like this:

[image]

Why is it displaying the description for `f` in extra boxes and how do I make it behave like a "normal" parameter?

Comment: It's not a "normal" parameter though. It's not a parameter of your function, it's a parameter of a parameter of your function.

Comment: Is this intentional - why not put the whole thing in a box then? Is there a way to not have it look completely out of place?

Comment: Looks fine to me - `something` is a closure and parameter of your function and is listed as such. `f` is a parameter of this closure, therefore it's displayed as a sub-section of the description of `something`

Comment: Displaying it below `something` is fine, that's not the problem. I'm talking about the box around it. There's no indication that `f` is actually a part of `something`, the box makes it look like it's something special or some extra thing that's not connected to anything else. Is there a way to get rid of that box?